# Insert Individual Records for Each Item in Array

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, android-studio

I'm posting strings from my Android Client and converting them to Arrays in `PHP`. User IDs and Book IDs are what I am trying to store in my database, but the problem I am having is that it stores fine when it's just one user and one book selected but when it is more than one user or more than one book, it says that the data is too long or data has been truncated for column.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I am trying to create a new record for each User ID in the array with a Book ID connected to it. *`Example: user["1121", "2171"] book["3"]`*

**DB**:

```
User_ID     |      Book_ID
------------+---------------
1121        |       3 
2171        |       3
```

Or the other way round so that there is 1 user but, for example, 2 `Book_ID`s. The database should have 2 records, same `User_ID` different `Book_ID`

**My Code**

Android Client (Converting ArrayLists to Strings and adding them to the Post Params):

```
 String attendees = TextUtils.join(",", ClassesAdapter.getAttendees());
 String lesson_iDs = TextUtils.join(",", Lesson_ClassesAdapter.getLesson_IDs());

// Adding string variables to watch param
 watch = new Watch(attendees, lesson_iDs);
```

Receiving the param in php and using `json_decode()` to convert to an array:

```
if(isset($_POST['watch'])){
$jsonwatch = $_POST['watch'];
$array = json_decode($jsonwatch, true);
$response["error"]=! ($db_watch->storeClass($array['attendees'], $array['lesson_iDs']));
```

*** Note I do also store dates in the `storeClass()` function using `NOW()`*